# Can't get ride of the index column of my excel sheet in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this excel file:

```
Sentence
12 rue magnol à montpellier
5 avenue de la chantroune 38190 villard bonnot
```

And this code:

```
import pandas as pd

excel = pd.read_excel(open('Data.xlsx','rb'), sheetname='Data', index=False)
print(excel)
```

The first row becomes the columns names, so everything is good but, when I print, the column of the index in my excel file seems to get into my dataframe and I just can't get ride of it:

```
                                              Sentence  \
0                          12 rue magnol à montpellier   
1       5 avenue de la chantroune 38190 villard bonnot
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a DataFrame without the indexes.

However, excel.values will give you the raw NumPy ndarray without the indexes.

When writing back to a csv for instance, you can set index=False so that no index is written back to the file.

Comment: Ho ok gotcha ! Thank you, also, if I wanna print in the console: `for row in df.tolist(): print(row)` can be a workaround :) I mean, I did that for Series that I got from the DataFrame